# Live USB -add files?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I have Ubuntu on a USB drive, each time i boot it it is a clean installation, i.e. there is no persistent files. I would like to be able to boot it up, and access a couple f files from the USB... as in have files already in the Ubuntu system? Is there anyway of adding them to installation files on the USB?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Presistent USB to be able to do so.  To create a presistent USB you can use the [universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).

Once you run the program, you can set the amount of space that you want to accomplish your task.  You can do that under Step 4 in the program.  See image below.

[image]